# Haskell constants in functions

Tags: haskell

I was wondering if someone could explain to me what (-2)(-2) in the brackets in the first line of the code stand for. I am new to Haskell and I’m trying to understand.

```
to_up_left board (x, y, t, c) (-2)(-2) = to_up_left board (x, y, t, c) x y
to_up_left board (x, y, t, c) 0 _ = []
to_up_left board (x, y, t, c) _ 9 = []
to_up_left board ((-1), y, t, c) _ _ = []
to_up_left board (x, y, t, c) _x _y =  if (empty_field board (_x-1) (_y+1))  && (t == 'a' || t == 'A' )
                            then    concat [decode_x x ++ decode_y y ++ "-" ++ decode_x (_x-1) ++ decode_y (_y+1)]:     to_up_left board (x, y, t, c) (_x-1)  (_y+1) 
                            else if   (friend_on_field board  (_x-1) (_y+1)) &&   (t == 'a' || t == 'A' )
                                then   concat [decode_x x ++ decode_y y ++ "-" ++ decode_x (_x-1)++ decode_y (_y+1)]: []
                                else     []
```

Comment: to match with negative numbers, otherwise it will be interpreted as `(to_up_left board (x, y, t, c)) -(2 (-2))`.

Answer (score 4):

> if someone could explain to me what `(-2) (-2)` in the brackets in the first line of the code stand for.

This is to pattern match with negative numbers, otherwise it will be interpreted as

```
(to_up_left board (x, y, t, c)) - (2 (-2))
```

and it thus seems that you are defining a `(-)` function. Negative numbers should thus be specified between parenthesis. The parenthesis have no special meaning: you can nest it an arbitrary number of times `((-2))` for example.

Comment: So it maches x and y to take negative numbers as values as well ?  
Thank you 

Comment: Does it match any negative numbers, or -2 specifically?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson: `-2` specifically. here

Answer (score 3):

The function `to_up_left` has 4 arguments.  In the top line:

- `board` is the first argument
- `(x, y, t, c)` is the second argument
- `(-2)` is the third argument
- `(-2)` is the fourth argument.

The `(-2)` arguments need their parentheses because otherwise `-` would act as a binary operator.

Haskell function definitions do pattern matching:

- `board` names its argument, just as in C-like languages
- `(x,y,t,c)` expects a 4-tuple, and binds the 4 elements to separate names
- `(-2)` checks to see if the argument is equal to `-2`

  - if the third and fourth arguments are not both `-2`, try the next pattern